# multithread issue with NTLM and Java Apache httpclient 4.5.6

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpclient-4.x, ntlm

I have a stand-alone Java client trying to do RMI through a NTLM proxy.
It's multithreaded.
I'm using Apache httpclient 4.5.6.
I've got the proxy on a 5 minute timeout cycle.

The basic case works, reauthenticating every 5 minutes when challenged by the proxy, as long as 2 threads don't make a request at the same time at exactly the time the proxy times out. Then it fails. Once it fails, all subsequent attempts fail.

I've attached a wireshark screenshot to clarify (screenshot is from 4.5.2 but I upgraded to 4.5.6 and saw the same behavior).

[image: wireshark screenshot]

A good cycle looks like

- Client tries CONNECT (no NTML flags)
- Proxy replies with 407 (no NTML flags)
- Client tries CONNECT again with ntlm messagetype NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE
- Proxy replies with 407 NTLMSSP_CHALLENGE
- Client does CONNECT with NTLMSSP_AUTH and my credentials.
- Proxy replies with 200, and we are good to go for another 5 minutes.

A bad cycle looks like

- Client tries CONNECT (no NTML flags)
- Proxy replies with 407 (no NTML flags)
- Client tries CONNECT again with ntlm messagetype NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE
- Client tries CONNECT (no NTML flags)
- Proxy replies with 407 (no NTML flags)
- Proxy replies with 407 NTLMSSP_CHALLENGE
- A whole bunch more CONNECTs and 407s without NTML flags within a few seconds.

to me this looks like a multithread race condition in non-threadsafe code.

With Apache httpclient 4.5.2 it just propogated the 407 and I detected it in CloseableHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode().
With Apache httpclient 4.5.6 I see this

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Auth scheme is null
    at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.notNull(Asserts.java:52)
    at org.apache.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator.ensureAuthScheme(HttpAuthenticator.java:229)
    at org.apache.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator.generateAuthResponse(HttpAuthenticator.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.createTunnelToTarget(MainClientExec.java:484)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:411)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
```

Any ideas how to protect against this or work around it or recover from it?
(beside sync on the calls, which would slow down an already slow app a lot)

some code snippets from the app:

```
// this is done only once
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClients.custom();
SocketConfig.Builder socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom();
RequestConfig.Builder requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom();
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
builder.setProxy(proxy);
requestConfig.setProxy(proxy);
builder.setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy());
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
String localHost = getLocalHostname();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort, AuthScope.ANY_REALM, "ntlm"),
    new NTCredentials(user, password, localHost, domain));
builder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
builder.setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig.build());
builder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig.build());
CloseableHttpClient client = builder.build();

...

// cached, we use the same one every time in accordance with section 4.7 of
// https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/authentication.html
HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
context.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);

...

// new HttpPost every time
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(uri);
postMethod.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(bytesOut.toByteArray()));
response = client.execute(postMethod, context);
```

Comment: Is `HttpClientContext` being used by multiple threads concurrently?

Comment: yes. section 4.7 of https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/authentication.html says to always use the same one, although it doesn't mention threads.

Comment: __Do__ __not__.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext` instances are perfectly thread-safe. However some attributes stored in the context such as authentication handshake state are obviously not. Make sure that `HttpContext` instances do not get updated concurrently and the problem should go away.

Comment: How do I make sure of that? My code is not updating `HttpClientContext`, that is occurring somewhere deep in the apache httpclient code. The only thing I do with context is pass it into `CloseableHttpClient.execute(HttpUriRequest, HttpContext)`

Comment: Thank you, this is what I did and it seems to be working so far.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Oleg, this is what I did and it seems to be working so far (too long to post as a comment on your answer, but I wanted to share my code)

```
// I use the base version when not going through a proxy
public class HttpClientContextFactory {
    public HttpClientContext create() {
        return HttpClientContext.create();
    }
}

// I use this when I go through a NTLM proxy
private HttpClientContextFactory getNtlmContextFactory(
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider) {
    return new HttpClientContextFactory() {
        ThreadLocal<HttpClientContext> tlContext = ThreadLocal
                .<HttpClientContext> withInitial(() -> {
                    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
                    context.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                    return context;
                });

        @Override
        public HttpClientContext create() {
            return tlContext.get();
        }
    };
}

// then do this when I connect to the server
response = client.execute(postMethod, contextFactory.create());
```